# How to clone a local repository on remote server?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a scenario like below:

I don't have direct access from my server to bitbucket repository(in different network).I have access only from my laptop to bitbucket repository and also i have ssh access from my laptop to server

So every time i do some changes in my server, I have to copy that code to my laptop using scp and then push that to bitbucket repository

Is it anyway to clone this local laptop repo so that if i do any changes on my server, it will be pushed automatically to bitbucket or atleast the code copied to laptop repo automatically so that i can just run git push command from my laptop to push that to bitbucket repo

Please advice me how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Using `scp` suggests that you have ssh access. If so, consider setting up your ssh system to use the server as a jump host. This is purely an ssh operation—Git is not involved here—so see ssh documentation instead of Git documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also i have ssh access from my laptop to server

That means you can pull the server repo from your laptop

```
 cd /path/to/laptop/repo
 git remote add server ssh://remoteUser@server/path/to/server/repo
 git pull server master
 git push
```